# How to set a private variable for a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scope

I would like to create a simple plugin, which works with the text of the element as a default value, or you can set this value, when you call the plugin.

But if I don't set the value, and call the plugin for more than one element, the default value getting multiplied.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.reText = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            label : $(this).text()
        }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            $(this).text(settings.label);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

call:

```
$(function() {
    $('div').reText();
});
```

the result:

```
<div>text 1</div>
<div>text 2</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kreestian/L3tp9/)

I know, the problem is the `settings`'s scope, but I don't know how to resolve the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the settings variable declaration inside of each function, so that it will different for each element / div.

The sample code will be as follows:

```
 return this.each(function() {
    var settings = $.extend({
      label : $(this).text()
    }, options);

    $(this).text(settings.label);
 });
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3tp9/1/)

Comment: Ok, but what if i want to use the settings on another method to? I forget to write this case...

Comment: What exactly you want? Give us the complete test case.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll write another code for that case, but this is a good answer, accept this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it has to be inside the each loop, so that each element in the given set will gets its own default value

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.reText = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var settings = $.extend({
                label: $(this).text()
            }, options);
            $(this).text(settings.label);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6rZ6n/)

Answer (score 0):

In reponse to your further query about how to give other methods access to your private variables, you can simply set a 'self' context at the start of your iteration and then reference that. All other methods declared within your iteration can still reference `self.settings`, although they themselves will be within a new function context.

```
$.fn.reText = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = this;

        self.settings = $.extend({
            label : $(this).text()
        }, options);

        $(this).text(self.settings.label);

        self.DoSomething = function() {
            console.log(self.settings.label);
        }
    });
};
```

Or, if you are outside the scope of your iteration loop, you could set your instance data using the Jquery `.data` method, given your dependance on jquery.

```
// Store
$(this).data("reText", self.settings);
...
console.log($(this).data("reText"))
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgJ8H/)

Comment: It's seems good, but i post the problem [more detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853426/variable-scope-in-a-jquery-plugin). Would you take a look on it?